# Why do my images move positions when double clicking them?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm encountering this weird issue where when there's more than one image in the browser uploaded followed by double clicking (liking) an image, the images swap positions by themselves.

I've made a laundry list of attempts of trying to debug this in my JS code but to no avail.

- Tried giving the `preview` variable a position of `absolute` (i.e. `preview.style.position = "absolute";`).
- Tried giving the `preview` variable a position of `fixed` (i.e. `preview.style.position = "fixed";`).

These are just two attempts I named out of the many.  I'm not even sure if I was on the right track.  What's wrong in my code and how can I fix it?

Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2vyothpu/

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="file-input-wrapper">
    <input type="file" id="file-input" name="files" style="display: none;"/>
    <label for="file-input" id="LblBrowse">
        Upload your photo!
    </label>
</div>
```

Here's my JS:

```
function previewImages() {
    // HTML for file upload
    // <input id="file-input" type="file">

    var preview = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(preview);

    if (this.files) {
        [].forEach.call(this.files, readAndPreview);
    }

    function readAndPreview(file) {
        // Make sure `file.name` matches our extensions criteria
        if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {
            return alert(file.name + " is not an image");
        } // else...

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
            var image = new Image();
            image.height = 100;
            image.title = file.name;
            image.src = this.result;

            var date = Date.now();
            var d = new Date(parseInt(date, 10));
            var ds = d.toString('MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss');
            console.log(ds);

            var initialCountOfLikes = 0;
            var zeroLikes = document.createElement('h1');
            var zeroLikesTextNode = document.createTextNode(initialCountOfLikes + " likes");

            zeroLikes.appendChild(zeroLikesTextNode);

            preview.appendChild(image);
            preview.appendChild(zeroLikes);

            image.ondblclick = function (event) {
                if (initialCountOfLikes === 0) {
                    console.log("Inside if block");
                    initialCountOfLikes++;
                    console.log("initialCountOfLikes++ => " + initialCountOfLikes);
                } else if (initialCountOfLikes === 1) {
                    console.log("inside second else if block");
                    initialCountOfLikes--;
                    console.log("initialCountOfLikes-- => " + initialCountOfLikes);
                }
                zeroLikesTextNode.nodeValue = initialCountOfLikes + " likes";
                document.body.appendChild(preview);
            };
        });
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}

document.querySelector('#file-input').addEventListener("change", previewImages);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images swap position because every time you double click on an image, it gets appended to the body. Its position in the DOM tree is changed it becoming the last child of body.

Here is your double click handler, I've commented the last line below because that's the one that re-appends the image to the body thus changing its position.
You can remove it entirely, I left it there for reference.

```
image.ondblclick = function (event) {
    if (initialCountOfLikes === 0) {
        console.log("Inside if block");
        initialCountOfLikes++;
        console.log("initialCountOfLikes++ => " + initialCountOfLikes);
    } else if (initialCountOfLikes === 1) {
        console.log("inside second else if block");
        initialCountOfLikes--;
        console.log("initialCountOfLikes-- => " + initialCountOfLikes);
    }
    zeroLikesTextNode.nodeValue = initialCountOfLikes + " likes";
    // document.body.appendChild(preview);
};
```

Comment: that makes total sense, didn't think of it this way. yo thank you man.  I was stuck on this for 2 days, can't believe this is all it was ...wow.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you look at this line of code:

```
document.body.appendChild(preview);
```

What you are essentially doing here is appending the whole preview(image + text) to the **end of the document**. What you actually want to do is just increment `initialCountOfLikes` and update the text.